# SQL Server 2008 R2 "Server Accounts" installation setup question

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I am installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Web on my Mac (OS X Leopard), running Parallels 6 and Windows 7...

The database will be used for ASP.NET development purposes. I am trying to figure out what Windows Accounts to use for each SQL 2008 Service when prompted by the installation (e.g. SQL Server Agent, SQL Server Database Engine, SQL Server Reporting Services, SQL Server Full-Text Filter Daemon Launcher and SQL Server Browser).  If I can simply create a new user account and use it for each service, that is okay, I've seen an example of that [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2008/07/15/installing-sql-server-2008-rc0.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage).  I guess my concerns are twofold:

1. Making sure that the accounts I wind up using have the proper
   privileges suitable for vs2010 development/debugging.
2. Making sure that the accounts I wind up using do not pose any security concerns
   associated with my mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Windows 7 is not a [supported OS for SQL Server Web Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#Web32), so it's unlikely that what you're trying to do will even work. I don't know anything about Parallels, but if it is a similar concept to VMWare then I guess that your Windows 7 installation should behave like any other Windows 7 installation.

Second, the considerations for SQL Server service accounts are [well documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28SQL.105%29.aspx), including security issues, and so is the [setup required for debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0fk6z6e.aspx) in Visual Studio.

Finally, and for what it's worth, developing software of any kind in an 'unusual' environment that isn't the same as the environment where the application will be deployed usually leads to problems. It's just much easier and more reliable to develop in a 'native' environment, although I appreciate that if you're doing this as a hobby then you may not be able to have exactly the resources you want. If you're doing this professionally, you should be able to justify the cost of a native development environment.

Comment: Windows 7 works fine for all kinds of SQL Server Editions. It's not supported per se, as it's intended to run on servers running 2008R2 (and other server OS-es instead) - but even so, it's likely that what he's trying to do will work just fine.

Comment: @cairnz Yes, I'm sure you're right, but spending time working on an unsupported configuration is always a risky thing to do. At best it works but you still never know when it will break in a 'real' environment (will it still work after the next patch or servicepack?); at worst you just can't make it work and your time is wasted.